# Custom Xaml crop control for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1**  app that requires me to **crop** an image to produce another square image **(250 by 250)**. I need **xaml and code behind sample code** that I can be use to do the cropping. The examples found online are for the **old** WP8 and they are not very helpful.Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: please share code you have tried so far or link of examples you found not working for you

Comment: 1. [Crop Image](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.co.ke/2014/03/windowsphone-8-crop-image-area-with.html) is an old post for wp8 which is not applicable to wp8.1. [Crop Image With A rectangle](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.co.ke/2014/11/windowsphone-image-crop-with-rectangle.html) is also applicable to wp8 only.

Comment: The only thing I need is a square(250 px) that I can drag over the image and I crop the section of the image selected using the square. I have been trying to customize code but am not successful. I wish microsoft would be more serious and provide such basic controls.

Comment: I did find a solution , there is this article I came across and it has two parts.[Part 1](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-image-cropping-windows) and [Part 2](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-image-cropping-windows-0) proved helpful in finding a solution with minimal modifications such as using WriteableBitmapEx methods for cropping instead. I hope this will help someone in future and save them the pain I went through.

Comment: write it as answer to your own question

Comment: I cant answer my own question right now. Maybe you should upvote the question so that I get enough reputation to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, there is this article I came across and it has two parts.[Part 1](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-image-cropping-windows) and [Part 2](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-image-cropping-windows-0) proved helpful in finding a solution with minimal modifications such as using WriteableBitmapEx methods for cropping instead. I hope this will help someone in future and save them the pain I went through.

Here is also some code I used to center crop my image

```
 public static WriteableBitmap centerCropImage(WriteableBitmap image)
    {


        int originalWidth = image.PixelWidth;
        int originalHeight = image.PixelHeight;

        //Getting the new width
        int newWidth = originalWidth > originalHeight? originalHeight : originalWidth;

        //Calculating the cropping points
        int cropStartX, cropStartY;
        if(originalWidth > originalHeight){
            cropStartX = (originalWidth - newWidth)/2;
            cropStartY = 0; 
        }
        else{
            cropStartY = (originalHeight - newWidth)/2;
            cropStartX = 0; 
        }

        //Then use the following values to get the cropped image

        var cropped = image.Crop(new Rect(cropStartX, cropStartY, newWidth, newWidth));

        //Then resize the new square image to 250 by 250 px
        var resized = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Resize(cropped, 250, 250, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor);

        return resized;
    }
```